# PHP: How good is garbage collector?

Tags: php, garbage-collection

Do you do something manually in your projects after PHP 5.3?

Comment: Please clarify your question more, be specific...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, I implement `__destruct()` everywhere to clean up object trees and close connections, etc.. This is pretty important for long running PHP code.

I recently found [gc_collect_cycles](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php). It's pretty helpful as well. It's as good as cleaning up your variables yourself, but from what I read it also has a small performance penalty.